# PyMongo authentication with docker

Tags: python, mongodb, authentication, pymongo

I'm having some problems to authenticate a newly created user in MongoDB. My setup is the MongoDB 4.4.2 in a container and python 3.8.

I have created a user as follows:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

host = "mongodb://root_user:root_password@172.20.0.3:27017"
DB_NAME = "test"
client = MongoClient(host)
test_db = client[DB_NAME]
test_db.command("createUser", "TestUser", pwd="TestPwd", roles=["readWrite"])
```

So far, so good: I simply added the `TestUser` to the database `test`, and so I see when I query the collection `client.system.users.find({'user': 'TestUser'})`, I get the test user with `db: test`.

Now if I want to test this user connection with

```
host = "mongodb://TestUser:testPwd@172.20.0.3:27017"
```

it shows an authentication failure: `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed.`

I can connect via the shell inside the container but not via pymongo and I tried already to connect specifying the authentication method, the authentication database and neither worked so far.

Any hints would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's unclear which database you're authenticating against. You can set your authenticationDatabase by using `authSource=test`. Which brings your URI to `mongodb://TestUser:testPwd@172.20.0.3:27017/?authSource=test`. As per the docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/

Comment: Oh man, I was setting all the time `authSource=system` in my experiments becuase it is in `system.users` where this entry exists, but I completely missed the point that the `authSource` is the database to which I try to connect to. Thank you very much @RobertSeaman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues.

1. As the commenter notes, you are creating the user in the `test` database; by default MongoDB will look for credentials in the `admin` database if `authSource` is not specified. Therefore you will need to append `/<optional database name>?authSource=test` to your connection string.
2. You create your account with password `TestPwd`, but on the connection string you have `testPwd`; so this won't authenticate.

So, assuming your password is definitely `TestPwd`, your connection string should be:

```
mongodb://TestUser:TestPwd@172.20.0.3:27017/test?authSource=test
```

Comment: Indeed, I re-wrote the other connection string instead of copy-paste it. My bad! In your answer, tho, I think you meant port 27017, not 27019.

Comment: oh yeah sorry 27017 - edited it. Glad you  got it working.